# Multiple UserPropagators

Tags: z3, z3py

With the recent addition of [UserPropagators](https://microsoft.github.io/z3guide/programming/Example%20Programs/User%20Propagator), I'm wondering if the solver is able to safely support more than one in the same context?

Comment: I don't see why that should be a problem. Did you try that and have issues with it? Note that this sort of question might be more suitable for: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions

Comment: Thanks for the comment @alias, yes I had some errors when trying to use two trivial propagators together, so I was wondering if that was consistent with the expectations.

Comment: According to the discussion, looks like this isn't supported at all. On stack-overflow, you can answer/accept your own questions. Please add a summary as an answer and accept it so as to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this isn't supported, based on the discussion here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions/6382